# Detect Camera photo folder

Tags: java, android, camera, directory, photo

My default Camera application saves photos to /mnt/sdcard2/Photo folder.
Say, how I can detect this folder by code?

I have found this code, but it does not help me:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
// Returns /mnt/sdcard/Pictures
tv.setText(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath());
// Returns /mnt/sdcard/DCIM
tv.append("\n" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath());
setContentView(tv);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If neither `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` nor `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` returns the directory used by the device's default camera app, and the user did not specify a particular location, then the authors of that camera app are idiots. The *default* camera app should store its photos in a *default* directory (usually `DIRECTORY_DCIM`) by *default*, in the absence of user intervention.

Since any app can elect to store its files wherever it wants to, there is no way to determine ahead of time that:

- a device's default camera app was written by idiots
- the user chose a different camera app, that may or may not have been written by idiots, because that particular camera app has reasons for not storing the images in a particular location
- the user configured a camera app (default or otherwise) to store photos in an alternative location

IOW, there's nothing you can really do, other than to revise your plans to not assume photos reside in any given location.

Comment: I changed the camera setting to save photos in a convenient place for me.
I think that the application stores it in its settings and the settings are different for each application. I realized that he asked a stupid question. You have helped me to find a solution for my problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare : I understand what you mean. So the solution should be load All Folders have images inside, correct? You know how to do?

Answer (score 1):

do something like this:

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    File file = null;
    if (isExternalSDCard()) {
        file = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "photo.jpg");
    } else {
        file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(),
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        file = new File(file, "photo.jpg");
    }
    if (file != null && file.exists()) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),
                options);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

photo.jpg which is the name of your image.

for all files in the directory:

```
File[] filesPhotos = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).listFiles();
```

^^

my code isExternalSDCard:

```
private static boolean isExternalSDCard() {
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // We can read and write the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // We can only read the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but
        // all we need
        // to know is we can neither read nor write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
    return mExternalStorageAvailable && mExternalStorageWriteable;
}
```